# How to map a function over a tree in haskell?

Tags: function, haskell, tree

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
  deriving (Show, Eq)

mapTree :: (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b
maptree f Empty = Empty
mapTree f (Node x l r) = Node (f x) (mapTree f l) (mapTree f r)
```

This is the function I've written to try to map a function over a tree but it doesn't work as expected

Why does my function return "Non-exhaustive patterns in function mapTree"?

Comment: `maptree` is not `mapTree` -- you have a small typo. If you don't have warnings enabled, enable them (`-Wall`): they should report these kinds of issue.

Comment: You defined two functions; `maptree` is only defined on empty trees, `mapTree` on non-empty trees.